# Google Analytics - Unique events are not unique by Action name

Tags: events, google-analytics

I have Google Analytics (GA) event tracking set up. When I see "Top Events" report, why the "Unique Events" number do not match with number of rows displayed below. [see screen: [click here](http://tinypic.com/r/346ql2p/6) ] These rows display one action name per row and the action names are all unique (I checked all 23 rows for unique action names). So total number of rows displayed should be equal to Unique Events number - isn't it?

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The unique event count for an action is the number of visits in which that action took place.

The total unique events in this report should equal the sum of unique events on all rows, not the number of rows. This is because a unique event is based on unique action-visit combinations, and each row has a different action.

In other words, if an action is repeated within a visit, the unique event count is not incremented, but otherwise it is.

So if one of the rows has 2 unique events that would mean that the event action was triggered in 2 separate visits, and both these visits would be included in the overall unique events.

In your example, the first 10 actions in your report only occurred for 1 visit each (they may even have all been the same visit - you can't tell from this report).

So I'm guessing that on the second page of your example there are two rows with 0 unique events, and the rest have 1 unique event - so that they add up to 21 unique events.